# QSqlQuery (MySQL) to QTableWidget freezing user interface

Tags: qt

```
void TableWidget::load()
{
    QSqlQuery query(_db);
    query.setForwardOnly(true);
    query.prepare("SELECT * FROM " + _name);
    query.exec();
    int lines = query.size();
    int columns = query.record().count();
    setRowCount(lines);
    int row = 0;
    while (query.next()) {
        for(int column = 0; column < columns; column++)
            setItem(row, column, new QTableWidgetItem(query.value(column).toString()));
        row++;
    }
    resizeColumnsToContents();
}
```

I'm using the above code to load data from MySQL to a QTableWidget. How big is the data? Around 1k5 rows of ~100 columns (over the internet). And it freezes the application user (graphical) interface in a notable way. How to make it smooth?

I have threads in mind (as last resort). But, as this is already a slot I think it is aready going in a separate thread (isn't?).

Comment: `But, as this is already a slot I think it is aready going in a separate thread (isn't?).` - no. Use threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> as this is already a slot I think it is aready going in a separate
>   thread (isn't?)

No, Qt apps normally work in one thread, and in particular all GUI code must run in the main thread. Sounds like you are confused about what "asynchronous code" in Qt means. It usually (unless you use threads yourself, or use a class which is explicitly documented to use threads internally) means, that you write slots, and connect signals, and then when slot is called it does its thing and returns as quickly as it can, and all this works in one thread. No slots are executed concurrently (so no threading issues). And if the slot takes a long time to execute, then you will get GUI freezing, because it is in that one thread.

Having a widget slot executing in another thread is generally a bad idea: it can't call any of the widget's own methods, they're not thread safe, so it's very easy to create bugs by accidentally calling wrong methods. Use Qt signals and slots to communicate between threads, and if you add any methods to be called from different threads, be extra careful about what you do in them.

---

Most direct fix to question code would to be create new `QObject` subclass, and put that `load()` method there, and then move that entire object to run in another thread. Then instead of `setItem()` call shown above, emit a signal with necessary information, and connect it to a slot in `TableWidget`, which does the `setItem()` (as long as connection type is automatic or queued, signals between threads will be handled by Qt event loop).

To understand how Qt threading works, you can [read the docs starting here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html), but you can also start by *carefully* using advice like in [this blog](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/), to move your `load()` method to a new subclass and then execute in a different thread.

Once that works, you should probably emit more data per signal to improve efficiency: probably a row of data, possibly bigger chunks, possibly even *all* the data in one signal, depending on just how much data you have. Qt containers are copy-on-write, so passing them between threads as signal arguments is not extra overhead, no matter how big they are (they won't get copied, unless you modify them).

Comment: I'm in the process of doing it. Trying to use `QList<QList<QVariant> >` as the return type for `load()`, which will carry data from thread back to the `TableWidget`. But I got the following: `QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QList<QList<QVariant> >'
(Make sure 'QList<QList<QVariant> >' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)`. Guess I have to typedef `typedef QList<QList<QVariant> > data;
qRegisterMetaType<data>("data");`, but then stopped at `error: specializing member '::qRegisterMetaType<data>' requires 'template<>' syntax
 qRegisterMetaType<data>("data");`

Comment: @KcFnMi You can use typedef, but more importly, you need to register the type to Qt meta type system. A [doc link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE). Anyway, if that's not clear enough, and you have a new question like *How do I register a metatype like QList<QList<QVariant> >"*, then please ask a new separate question :)